# HTML Dom get dynamic table's drop action?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to get drop event , but I can't able to get it. Please .
**I want to show savechanges() function on every drop actions**.

```js
$('#drag').sortable();
function savechanges() {
  var table = document.getElementById("t01");
 var x = document.getElementById("t01").rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
 alert("First Row Name Value is : "+x);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.css">
<style>

table {
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid #494345;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}
table#t01 th {
    background-color: #FF3F67;
    color: white;
}
table#t01 tr:hover {
    background-color: #FFF44D;
}

table#t01 tr:hover td {
    background-color: transparent; /* or #000 */
}

</style>
 
</head>

<table id="t01" class="table table-bordered pagin-table" width="100%" style="border: 2px solid #494345;border-collapse: collapse;"><tbody><tr style="cursor:no-drop"><th style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">No</th><th style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;"> Name</th><th style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;">URL</th><th width="5%" style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;"></th></tr></tbody><tbody id="drag" class="ui-sortable">
<tr style="padding: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(73, 67, 69); cursor: move;" class="ui-sortable-handle"><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">1</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="55%">Google</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="30%"><a onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;blue&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;#F52887&quot;;" style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor" target="_blank">Test Link</a></td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="5%"><i onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;red&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;black&quot;;" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteFeed('aasasa|!Name-URL!|https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor')" class="material-icons">highlight_off</i></td></tr>
<tr style="padding: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(73, 67, 69); cursor: move;" class="ui-sortable-handle"><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">2</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="55%">GitHub</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="30%"><a onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;blue&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;#F52887&quot;;" style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor" target="_blank">Test Link</a></td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="5%"><i onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;red&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;black&quot;;" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteFeed('aasasa|!Name-URL!|https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor')" class="material-icons">highlight_off</i></td></tr><tr style="padding: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(73, 67, 69); cursor: move;" class="ui-sortable-handle"><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">3</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="55%">Stackoverflow</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="30%"><a onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;blue&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;#F52887&quot;;" style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.google.com.mm/search?q=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th&amp;rlz=1C1CHBF_enMM732MM732&amp;oq=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th+&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57.6073j0j9&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8" target="_blank">Test Link</a></td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="5%"><i onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;red&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;black&quot;;" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteFeed('AASASA|!Name-URL!|https://www.google.com.mm/search?q=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th&amp;rlz=1C1CHBF_enMM732MM732&amp;oq=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th+&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57.6073j0j9&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8')" class="material-icons">highlight_off</i></td></tr></tbody></table>


<a onclick="savechanges();" style="text-decoration:none;" id="view-source" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--accent mdl-color-text--accent-contrast">Save</a>
```

Please try to my code work.

My main purpose is to get drop actions on this table, to save new value changes to database dynamically. Thank you for reading my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Sortable `stop` event

```js
$('#drag').sortable({
        stop: function( ) {
           savechanges();
        }
    });
function savechanges() {
  var table = document.getElementById("t01");
 var x = document.getElementById("t01").rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
 alert("First Row Name Value is : "+x);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.css">
<style>

table {
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid #494345;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}
table#t01 th {
    background-color: #FF3F67;
    color: white;
}
table#t01 tr:hover {
    background-color: #FFF44D;
}

table#t01 tr:hover td {
    background-color: transparent; /* or #000 */
}

</style>
 
</head>

<table id="t01" class="table table-bordered pagin-table" width="100%" style="border: 2px solid #494345;border-collapse: collapse;"><tbody><tr style="cursor:no-drop"><th style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">No</th><th style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;"> Name</th><th style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;">URL</th><th width="5%" style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;"></th></tr></tbody><tbody id="drag" class="ui-sortable">

<tr style="padding: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(73, 67, 69); cursor: move;" class="ui-sortable-handle"><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">1</td>
<td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="55%">Google</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="30%"><a onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;blue&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;#F52887&quot;;" style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor" target="_blank">Test Link</a></td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="5%"><i onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;red&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;black&quot;;" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteFeed('aasasa|!Name-URL!|https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor')" class="material-icons">highlight_off</i></td></tr>

<tr style="padding: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(73, 67, 69); cursor: move;" class="ui-sortable-handle"><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">2</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="55%">GitHub</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="30%"><a onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;blue&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;#F52887&quot;;" style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor" target="_blank">Test Link</a></td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="5%"><i onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;red&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;black&quot;;" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteFeed('aasasa|!Name-URL!|https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor')" class="material-icons">highlight_off</i></td></tr>

<tr style="padding: 5px; border: 2px solid rgb(73, 67, 69); cursor: move;" class="ui-sortable-handle"><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="10%">3</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="55%">Stackoverflow</td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="30%"><a onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;blue&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;#F52887&quot;;" style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.google.com.mm/search?q=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th&amp;rlz=1C1CHBF_enMM732MM732&amp;oq=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th+&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57.6073j0j9&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8" target="_blank">Test Link</a></td><td style="padding: 5px;border: 2px solid #494345;" width="5%"><i onmouseover="this.style.color=&quot;red&quot;;" onmouseout="this.style.color=&quot;black&quot;;" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteFeed('AASASA|!Name-URL!|https://www.google.com.mm/search?q=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th&amp;rlz=1C1CHBF_enMM732MM732&amp;oq=%24(%27tbody%27).sortable()%3B+except+th+&amp;aqs=chrome..69i57.6073j0j9&amp;sourceid=chrome&amp;ie=UTF-8')" class="material-icons">highlight_off</i></td></tr></tbody></table>


<a onclick="savechanges();" style="text-decoration:none;" id="view-source" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--accent mdl-color-text--accent-contrast">Save</a>
```